# A recursion problem

Tags: expl3

I have a recursion as follows: `#1`~{root} and `#2`~{tree}, and {tree}~{{node}{...{branch_j}...}} and branch_j={node}{tree}. For the last level,  branch_j={node}{leaf}. I call 'path', {root}...{node}. I want to map input={root}{tree} to {...{{path}{leaf}}...} (ultimately, I want to do `\__erw_process:nn{path}{leaf}`). My attempt works only with up to `iter`=3 in the code. Could someone make suggestions to sort this out?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{unravel}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% ---
\cs_new_protected:Npn
\__erw_recurse:w #1 #2 / #3 #4 \q_recursion_stop 
{ \quark_if_recursion_tail_break:nN {#4} \tl_map_break:
  \tl_map_inline:nn{#2}
  {#1\__erw_recurse:w ##1 / #4 \q_recursion_stop} }

\cs_new_protected:Nn\erw_recurse_aux:nn
{ \__erw_recurse:w #1 / #2
  \q_recursion_tail
  \q_recursion_stop
  \prg_break_point:Nn \tl_map_break: {} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \erw_recurse_aux:nn{ne}

\cs_new_protected:Nn
\erw_recurse:nn
{ \texttt{iter=#2->}
  \erw_recurse_aux:ne{#1}
  { \prg_replicate:nn{#2}{ {iter} } } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \erw_recurse:nn{o}

% \use_none_delimit_by_q_recursion_stop:w⟨balanced text⟩\q_recursion_stop

\tl_set:Nn\l__erw_input_tl
{
  {curiosity} 
  {
    {
      {killed} 
      {
        {
          {the~cat}{leaf1}
        }
        {
          {the~mouse}{leaf2}
        }
      }
    }
    {
      {fulfilled}
      {
        {
          {the~cat}{leaf3}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

% In this case, desired **output**,
% {{curiosity}{killed}{the~cat}}{leaf1}
% {{curiosity}{killed}{the~mouse}}{leaf2}
% {{curiosity}{fulfilled}{the~cat}}{leaf3}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\erw_recurse:on{\l__erw_input_tl}{1}\par
\erw_recurse:on{\l__erw_input_tl}{2}\par
\erw_recurse:on{\l__erw_input_tl}{3}\par
\erw_recurse:on{\l__erw_input_tl}{4}\par

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you better describe (with a LaTeX code) the explicit structure of "the input" and the desired "output".  It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  Perhaps there are simpler ways...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes There are simpler problems, for sure, but that is the one I want to solve. I added the words 'input' and 'output' in the code.

Comment: It is just that I am guessing it looks like you are trying to parse a nested list.  If your input syntax is flexible, a package like `listofitems` can do that.  But maybe I misunderstand what you are attempting...or maybe your input syntax is not flexible.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\mytree{A:curiosity
   B:killed
     C:the~cat
       D:leaf1
     C:the~mouse
       D:leaf2
   B:fulfilled
     C:the~cat
       D:leaf3
}

\ignoreemptyitems
\setsepchar{A:/B:/C:/D:}
\readlist*\myarray{\mytree}

\noindent
\myarray[1,1]\\
\myarray[1,2,1]\\
\myarray[1,2,2,1]\\
\myarray[1,2,2,2]\\
\myarray[1,2,3,1]\\
\myarray[1,2,3,2]\\
\myarray[1,3,1]\\
\myarray[1,3,2,1]\\
\myarray[1,3,2,2]\\
\end{document}`